# Tradingview Fakeout indicator that monitors real-time price behaviour

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am trying to create an indicator that will monitor real-time price. Let's say current market price of eth/usd is at 110, and the price is still trending down, but I believe that 100 is an important price, as least it's a major swing low that can be a potential support for at least a bounce or even a reversal, ok, now I add my fakeout indicator, and input the swing low price: 100, and enter the entry price: 103, what I want the indicator to do is start monitoring price, when price drops below 100, and comes back up above 103, it will trigger my long entry. And we all know that price won't always drop below 100 and go straight line above 103, there might be some consolidation before it is traded above 103, what I only care is the first time price drops below 100, and the first time price goes above 103, I want the indicator to remember these two critical status, because my alert condition is based on these two status.

fakeout or stophunt, whatever you can it, it contains two parts, fakeout to the upside, we can it bull trap, fakeout to the downside, we can it bear trap, although I include long and short conditions in my code, but in reality, when I add alert for the indicator, I will only choose one condition, either long or short. I included a screenshot for bear trap example.

[image]

please take a look at my codes guys, the codes represents what I want to do, but I can't seem to get it to work, there isn't any useful outcome telling me where went wrong, so I am asking for your help.

Thank you so much!

```
//@version=4
study("Fakeout Indicator", overlay=true)

// Define Swing Price to monitor, and Entry Price to monitor
Swing_Price = input(100, title="Enter the swing price", type=input.float, confirm=true)
Entry_Price = input(103,title="Entry Price", type=input.float, confirm=true)


// Draw lines for Swing Price and Entry Price
plot(Swing_Price , title="Swing Price", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2, color=color.gray, trackprice=true,offset=-9999)
plot(Entry_Price , title="Entry Price", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2, color=color.gray, trackprice=true,offset=-9999)


// Initial variable that stores status for long condition
break_below_long = false
break_above_long = false

// Store the status when the first time price breaks above Swing Price, and the status when the first time price breaks below Entry_Price
break_below_long := nz(break_above_long[1]) or not crossunder(close, Swing_Price) ? false : true
break_above_long := nz(break_below_long[1]) and crossover(close, Entry_Price) ? true : false


// Initial variable that stores status for short condition
break_above_short = false
break_below_short = false

// Store the status when the first time price breaks above Swing Price, and the status when the first time price breaks below Entry_Price

break_above_short := nz(break_below_short[1]) or not crossover(close, Swing_Price) ? false : true
break_below_short := nz(break_above_short[1]) and crossunder(close, Entry_Price) ? true : false

// Long Condition
longCondition = break_above_long

// Short Condition
shortCondition = break_below_short

// alert Condition
alertcondition(shortCondition, title="shortCondition for Bull Trap", message="Bull Trap Occurs!")
alertcondition(longCondition, title="longCondition for Bear Trap", message="Bear Trap Occurs!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these?

```
longCondition = crossunder(close[1], Swing_Price) and crossover(close, Entry_Price) and min(close, 2) > Swing_Price
```

Similarly for short:

```
shortCondition = crossover(close[1], Swing_Price) and crossunder(close, Entry_Price) and max(close, 2) < Swing_Price
```